# problem with Check box selection when multiple gridview exists on the form

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on check box selection in a grid view. I have gone though the following link [Grid view checkboxes](http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/228_GridView_CheckBox_Selection_With_a_Twist.aspx)

This works fine when i am having one grid view on my form , but if i have multiple grid views then i am facing a problem in selection. So can any one help me or give me any other alternative solution which works exactly as the link i posted..

My problem is when i am having multiple grid view and selecting one header grid view the items in other grid view are selected so can any one give me the best method to achieve.

I am using master pages too in my application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help not exactly per your requirement bus some what it helps

http://dotnetspeaks.net/post/Checking-all-CheckBoxes-in-a-GridView-using-JQuery.aspx

Give the function name to another if you are using multiple grid view and also change the check boxes name and give the valid with respect to that function..

Even that code to work with some minor changes too

if you are using master change here in your code

```
 $("#GridView1 input[name$='cbSelect']") to

 $("#<%= GridView1.ClientID %> input[name$='cbSelect']")
```

Answer (score 1):

From your example, you only need to duplicate the function `IsMatch(id)`.
Do a IsMatch for each of your grid :
`IsMatchGridView1(id)`, `IsMatchGridView2(id)`, etc... with thier own pattern : `'^GridView1', '^GridView2', etc ...`

Then when selecting the parent checkbox from gridview2, if you use the `IsMatchGridView2(id)`, you should only select the right checkboxes from the right gridview.